# Android: Double tap listener on relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout, gesturedetector

On my activity there is a **FrameLayout** and a **RelativeLayout**, both are holding 5 **imageViews**. I have implemented **GestureDetector** on **FrameLayout** to detect **double tap**, now I want to **detect double tap** on **RelativeLayout** and also want to **get the id** of the **child** imageView on which the **doubleTap** has been done.

Comment: Isn't any double tap on any imageView a doubleTap on the layout? Why do you need a separate one for the layout? PS: double tap is not a very user-friendly touch gesture, have you considered a long click?

Comment: In that case I need to implement double tap detector on all the imageviews, right? Agree, but that is what the application demands.

Comment: Yes, I would implement one gesture detector with a switch for the views, the individual cases will work for each image and any case is good for the layout

Comment: I've used SimpleOnGestureListener g1 = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0){..} but there is no argument for view? @Ics